# Building with LLVM using CMake, LLVM Clang VS Path is wrong

Tags: windows, cmake, clang, llvm, clion

I am using Cmake, Clion, LLVM, CLang on Windows to build my project

I'm getting the following error

```
ninja: error: 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/DIA SDK/lib/amd64/diaguids.lib', needed by 'CheckClang.exe', missing and no known rule to make it
```

The error seems vague, I don't even have Visual Studio 2019 installed, I have Visual Studio 2022 installed (not on a default path), However I can't see a way to tell that my Visual Studio is located here.

I tried changing the generator option to VS 17 (2022), however got the same error with different formatting

CMakeLists :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)
project(CheckClang)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

# Set the path to your LLVM and Clang installation
set(LLVM_DIR "D:/Software/Installed/llvmclang/lib/cmake/llvm")
set(Clang_DIR "D:/Software/Installed/llvmclang/lib/cmake/clang")

find_package(LLVM REQUIRED CONFIG)
find_package(Clang REQUIRED CONFIG)

message(STATUS "Found LLVM ${LLVM_PACKAGE_VERSION}")
message(STATUS "Using LLVMConfig.cmake in: ${LLVM_DIR}")

# Set your project compile flags.
if (MSVC)
    # Set iterator debugging level
    add_compile_options(/D_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL=0)  # Change to 0, 1, or 2 as needed
endif ()

# E.g. if using the C++ header files
# you will need to enable C++11 support
# for your compiler.

include_directories(${LLVM_INCLUDE_DIRS})
separate_arguments(LLVM_DEFINITIONS_LIST NATIVE_COMMAND ${LLVM_DEFINITIONS})
add_definitions(${LLVM_DEFINITIONS_LIST})

# Your executable target
add_executable(CheckClang main.cpp)

# Find the libraries that correspond to the LLVM components
# that we wish to use
llvm_map_components_to_libnames(llvm_libs support core irreader)

# Other clang libs clangTooling clangAST clangASTMatchers clangBasic
# Link against LLVM libraries
#LLVMX86AsmParser # MC, MCParser, Support, X86Desc, X86Info
#LLVMX86Desc # MC, Support, X86AsmPrinter, X86Info
#LLVMX86AsmPrinter # MC, Support, X86Utils
#LLVMX86Info # MC, Support, Target
#LLVMX86Utils # Core, Support
#LLVMipo
#LLVMScalarOpts
#LLVMInstCombine
#LLVMTransformUtils
#LLVMipa
#LLVMAnalysis
#LLVMTarget
#LLVMOption # Support
#LLVMMCParser # MC, Support
#LLVMMC # Object, Support
#LLVMObject # BitReader, Core, Support
#LLVMBitReader # Core, Support
#LLVMCore # Support
#LLVMSupport
target_link_libraries(CheckClang ${llvm_libs})

#clangFrontend
#clangSerialization
#clangDriver
#clangParse
#clangSema
#clangAnalysis
#clangAST
#clangBasic
#clangEdit
#clangLex
#clangTooling
target_link_libraries(CheckClang clangTooling)
# These compile options are available /MD /MDd /MT /MTd
# Set the runtime library option for the target
target_compile_options(CheckClang PRIVATE /MD)
```

Comment: Probably, your installation of llvm or clang package is linked with Visual Studio 2019, which you had active at the time of installation. You need to update your installed packages.

Comment: I downloaded prebuilt llvm, @Tsyvarev how do I link with Visual Studio 2022, I don't want to build llvm and clang

Comment: As a first step, you could search e.g. for `diaguids` in the text files (`.cmake`) in `D:/Software/Installed/llvmclang/lib/cmake/llvm` and in `D:/Software/Installed/llvmclang/lib/cmake/clang`. That way you could determine whether given packages **actually** depends from the old Visual Studio.

Comment: I have found diaguids.lib in VS2022 installation but the path is wrong, I'm hesitant to to trying out copy pasting the file, don't know how many errors are coming next

Comment: I did try building llvm from source, But I got errors on windows, even after following the guide, installing python, gnuwin32

Comment: check out what I found

https://github.com/ziglang/zig/blob/9e402704e2fc01369dfbf2c9a20ac1ee7d66ca7c/CMakeLists.txt#L650C1-L657C1

Zig uses diaguids.lib when on MSVC Windows, I tried to something similar, The thing is they link their binary with diaguids but even after linking my executable, The error still occurs

Comment: Again: The wrong `diaguids.lib` file is linked by one of your **dependency**. Linking your project directly with the correct version of that library does NOT fix the the error. You need to find out which exact your dependency uses the wrong file. In the previous comment I have described how to search.